# Get Babel pre-transformed JS at runtime

Tags: javascript, babeljs, reactjs

Given some ES6 JS code that'll get transformed with Babel, is it possible to both have Babel transform it, and also get the pre-transformed code as a string at runtime? Example:

```
function render() {
  // Babel transforms this JSX to some JS objects
  return <div>text</div>;
}

var renderedValue = render();
var codeUsedToRenderValue = // how to get the string "<div>text</div>"?
```

With normal JavaScript, given a function, you can call `.toString()` and it'll give the string representation of the code at runtime. But since Babel does transformations at compile-time, the result is sometimes incoherent. Is there a way to get the original code?

Comment: You could serve the original files from your server. Usually when you need to access the source code at runtime, there's a better solution. Unless of course you're building some kind of interpreter/compiler/static-analyzer.

Comment: There is no server. I'm making a UI explorer that lists both how components render and the code used to render it.

Comment: Well, something has to be serving those files, even if it's just local files. No matter what, you would need to access the original source code files. That or write your own source map implementation and load the source maps generated by Babel. No matter what, you aren't going to be able to get the original format from the compiled code alone.